# Python iterating through dictionaries replacing strings

Tags: python, dictionary

im new to python.

I have to search through directories and find files which have the strings kyle and john in them and replace them with mike and jim respectively. Each file can have kyle or john or both.

Here is my code

```
import os
import fileinput
import sys

rootdir ='C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test'
searchTerms = {"kyle":"mike","john":"jim"}
#old= "kyle"
#new = "mike"

def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
            sys.stdout.write(line)

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
            path=subdir+'/'+file
            for oldline, newline in searchTerms.items():
                replaceAll(path,oldline,newline)
```

Now i have created a test folder which has in it sample.txt, in sample.txt i have the word kyle in it. but when i run the program the file has no contents and even kyle is not there.
Can you please tell me what im doing wrong. I think the problem is in my replaceAll func. In the line  `if searchExp in line` is not getting executed properly. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: did you try debugging your code using e.g. print statements? You can print `file` to check whether it is found, `line` to check your lines, line after regexp, ... This will help you answering your question by yourself! (sorry for not posting an answer, but this seems to be homework ;) )

Comment: no man, im learning python. This is a question i found somewhere. The actual question is much more complex. I have made it simple for myself. So this is a general doubt. This is not my homework. Ya i have tried putting print statements, in the oldline and newline kyle and mike are being stored but when i pass them to the func, i think there is something wrong. Also as u can see the commented lines if i just uncomment those out and remove for oldline,newline in searchTerms.items() and replace the next statement with replaceAll(path,old,new) its working fine.

Comment: Well to start off with, you are writing to stdout not to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write all lines - not only with changes because `fileinput.input()` (with `inplace=1`) copy text to temporaty file to read lines from it and clear oryginal file for writing all lines again - but you have to write all lines yourself.

You can move `sys.stdout.write(line)` as below to resolve problem.

```
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Without `inplace=1` you have to do it yourself - read all lines from oryginal file, write all lines to temporary file and at the end replace oryginal file with temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

`fileinput.input(file, inplace=1)` is called `in-place filtering`

Eg.

There is a `sample.txt` which have the line `kyle kyle kyle`

On the first step, the line `kyle kyle kyle` is processed into `mike mike mike`.

And then, the line `mike mike mike` will be treated as the new input line.

There is no "kyle" or "john" in the new line, so no output will be written to `sample.txt`.

---

Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput

Comment: so what should i do to replace kyle with mike in the sample.txt file. If i change inplace=0, then the output is being written in the console but not to the file. How should i write it into the file.

Comment: Maybe you can write the lines to a new file.

Comment: No dude i have to replace it in the same file.

Comment: You have to write all lines - not only with changes. Because python copy text to temporaty file to read lines from it and clear oryginal file (for writing) so you have write all lines.

Comment: I agree with @furas. His answer is great.